# Load and Edit Remote Data with Select2() 4.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a Problem with pluging Select2() v4.0. I want load remote data in mi Modal from boostrap and to edit this values. My code is:

HTML

```
 <select id="txtAsistentes" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%" />
```

JS

```
ControlToSelect2Format: function (controlId,ocultos) {
    var control = "#" + controlId;
    $(control).select2({          
        minimumInputLength: 2,  // minimumInputLength for sending ajax request to server
        width: 'resolve',   // to adjust proper width of select2 wrapped elements 
        tags: false,
        allowClear: false,
        multiple: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "/Home/SearchUserAD/",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {                 
                return { results: data.Results };
            }
        },          
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var id = $("#hdReservaId").val();
            if (id !== "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetAsistentesReserva/",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: { idReserva: id }                       
                }).done(function (data) {

                    callback(data.Results);
                })
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The InitSelection its ok, because I use the "select2.full.min.js"  but the problem is when I try to edit the values that InitSelection precharge to my select2 control. I lose the values and clear the control.

How can edit the initial values without remove the values?

My problem is when I want editing the data that I created and saved before. I don't know how editing with select2()

Thanks!

Comment: A select cannot be self closing, you must use `<select></select>`.

Comment: @KevinBrown My problem is when I want editing the data that I created and saved before. I don't know how editing with select2()

Answer (score 0):

Finally my solution have been to put this code after of select() initialization, and remove the code initSelection:

```
    var id = $("#hdReservaId").val();
    if (id !== "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetAsistentesReserva/",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: { idReserva: id }
        }).then(function (data) {
            data.Results.forEach(function (entry) {
                //alert(entry);
                var $option = $('<option selected>' + entry.text + '</option>').val(entry.id);
                $(control).append($option).trigger('change');
            });
            $(control).trigger('change');
        });
    }
```

if modal is opened for editing,  call ajax for get the editing data. With That method i can editing without problem the data from select2() multiselect .

Thank You for the support!!